# C# application installer (once)

Tags: c#, installation

At the moment I am developing an (C#) application and want to add an installer. Is it possible to create a setup/ installer that can only be run **once**? If the user needs to re-install the application, he needs to download a new installer. Is it also possible to bind the installar (.exe) to a (one) computer?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Why on God's green earth would you want this? What if the user wants to *repair* the existing installation *without* downloading a new installer (presumably with new bits included)? Are they just SOL?

Comment: I wan to add some kind of app protection, so users can't pass the installer to other people (if the installer is already used). I don't want to use a license server or people have to contact me for a serial key.

Comment: Fair enough, but that kind of checking should be performed by the *application* (e.g. on startup), not by the installer.

Comment: What kind of offline protection is ok, without a (license) server?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `$ProjectName.application` file to install the application (it's in the publish folder you specify in the project settings). If you publish a new version, the application will automatically install the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are many different ways you can go about this. I think mostly applications use the windows registry for these types of scenarios. You can write to the registry(add a key) and retrieve it when uninstalling. Depending on your needs you can either do something as simple as that or something more complicated like registering the workstation with combination to a serial number for that product instance.